# camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py buttons are disabled

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I'm trying to do a monocular camera calibration with camera_calibration package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration).
I can start "cameracalibrator.py" but the buttons "CALIBRATE","SAVE" and "COMMIT" are disabled. See:
[image: image description]

So I can't do the calibration.

These are my commands:

```
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src num-buffers=-1 device=/dev/video1 caps=\"video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,format=(fourcc)YUY2\" ! ffmpegcolorspace"
roscd gscam
cd bin
rosrun gscam gscam &
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x7 --square 0.039 /image:=gscam/image_raw &
```

And these are the node connections:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44961/camera_calibration-cameracalibrator.py-buttons-are-disabled/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find the fault!! I set the inner squares inside the checkboard (9x7) instead of the inner corners (8x6). So the right command is:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.039 /image:=gscam/image_raw
```

Thankyou however

---

Originally posted by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) with karma: 252 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The buttons are disabled until you've captured enough samples to calibrate.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-10-02**:
You need also different enough samples: try to move your camera or the calibration pattern around. Especially try different levels of zoom and place it around the corners of your image with different orientations...

**Comment by [YugalSharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/49911/yugalsharma/) on 2020-03-13**:
worked for me
i used the same chessboard print as used here.
colorful lines appear on chessboard(actual boxes:9x7).
the calibrate button appears only after sufficient(20-25) pics are taken from the video stream.
it takes some time to turn blue from grey.
when u click the calibrate button then save button will turn blue ,click it and the see the address(in terminal window) where camera calibration result data is saved.(maybe in zip format)
extract the zip and you will see there some photos and the yaml file.
the yaml file contain the calibration parameters for your camera.